# MySQL UPDATE with SELECT (mark "item" as read)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, sql-update

I have the following query which selects personal messages (PM) from "ac_pms" table. Additional info is fetching from other table - "ac_accounts" using `LEFT JOIN`. There is "`pm_read`" column in "`ac_pms`" table which define a PM is read or not. I need to set that field (`pm_read`) to "`1`" while selecting PMs.

```
SELECT p.*, a.seller_id, a.winner_id 
FROM `ac_pms` AS p 
LEFT JOIN `ac_accounts` AS a ON p.pm_for_lot = a.id 
WHERE (p.pm_from=[user_id] OR p.pm_to=[user_id]) 
  AND p.pm_for_lot=[account_id] 
ORDER BY p.pm_date DESC;
```

I cannot imagine where to insert `UPDATE` expression to `SET pm_read = 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `SELECT` with `UPDATE` in the same SQL statement.

However, you can `UPDATE` with `JOIN` like this:

```
UPDATE ac_pms AS p 
LEFT JOIN ac_accounts AS a ON p.pm_for_lot = a.id 
SET p.pm_read = 1
WHERE (p.pm_from=[user_id] OR p.pm_to=[user_id]) 
  AND p.pm_for_lot = [account_id];
```

Then you can make another `SELECT` after that.